# Fullscreen notifications in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to get notification when application entered fullscreen mode? Because I have to redraw images when app enters full screen, and now I can't do it because I don't know when app enters fullscreen.

I found method:

```
- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
```

but where I have to use it? Because in `NSWindow` class it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this function

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification{ 
}
```

This function get called whenever the size of the window changes.

Answer (score 5):

1. [Full-Screen API in NSWindowDelegate Protocol:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH6-SW4)

   The following notifications are sent before and after the window enters and exits full-screen mode:

   ```
   NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification

   NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification

   NSWindowWillExitFullScreenNotification

   NSWindowDidExitFullScreenNotification
   ```
2. [How to use delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)

Comment: And is it possible to do something like that:
`- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification {
    while (!NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification) {
        [self someMethod];
    }
}` ?

Comment: @hockeyman I would advise against that. That will keep you from entering full screen mode. That's called right before your window will enter full screen. If you want a loop to run, then I suggest using a timer or GCD. It depends on your specific case.